# Android studio bluetooth external keyboard and native keyboard

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth, native, external, custom-keyboard

I am developing an App in Android Studio, I have an external keyboard connecting by Bluetooth to the mobile device where my App is running.

There is a lot of literature on custom keyboard etc. I am a bit lost. I am looking for a recommended way to use interchangeably the native keyboard and my keyboard. In other words, if I produce a character with my external keyboard it should appear on the input screen of any App as if it was produced by the native keyboard.

Thank you.